# different icon in android studio project - Kotlin activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Android studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 and building an app.
In Android Studio, in the Project list of files, what is the difference between these 2 icons :

[image]

Both files above are activities files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is `Kotlin Class` - It contains only one class with the same class name i.e file name and the class name are the same

The second one is `Kotlin File` - Which contains multiple classes with different names

Comment: Or zero classes, or one class if there are also top-level functions/properties.

Comment: Yeah, if there's only a single top-level class in there, and its name matches the filename, Android Studio will use that class icon. If you change the class name or add anything else (like a top-level ``val``) the icon will change to the file one. There's nothing special about the file itself, you just get a specific icon depending on what's currently in it! When you have the option for ``New Kotlin Class/File``, the only difference is if you choose Class, it'll add ``class Whatever { }`` automatically instead of leaving the file empty